# How to avoid timeout error for cy.request()?

Tags: cypress

I am using cy.request() method to send API requests and read the response in my cypress tests. But sometimes the tests fail with the following error:

*CypressError: `cy.request()` timed out waiting `30000ms` for a response from your server.*

I have increased the timeout value by passing in *timeout: 50000* option in the request body, but still, it is failing sometimes especially when the response is huge. Is there any other way to avoid the request timeout error?

Below is my code:

```
cy.request({
    method: "POST",
    url:"http://localhost:3001/codes/search?searchText=" +searchText.replace(" ", "%20") +"&page[size]=100",
    body: {
      data: {
        type: "ern:code-search-request",
        attributes: {
          CodeCategory: filterOption
        }
      }
    },
    timeout: 50000
  }).then((response: any) => {return response;})
```

Comment: Hey Just curious, Have you tried to hit the endpoint in Postman or a similar tool and check the response time in that case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `responsetimeout` in cypress.json file. [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts:%7E:text=cy.wait()%20command.-,responseTimeout,-30000)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore in 2022 on ^12.0.1